# Find a pair of co-prime numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm, numbers, primes, sieve

We are given an array.

```
array size <= 1e4.

1 <= A[i] <= 1e18.
```

We can run a double loop to find gcd of each possible pair. Is there any optimized algorithm?

Comment: Think about what co-prime means and take a step back of using gcd. This hint may help to lead you to a O(n) solution.

Comment: @MrSmith42: in the *worst case* (all items are co-prime with one another, e.g. we have an array of distinct prime numbers) we have to output `n * (n - 1) / 2` pairs and have `O(n**2)` time complexity

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Since the problem is *to find a pair* that becomes the best case. As soon as the first pairs is tested the algorithm can halt.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: You are absolutely right, if we have to find **all pairs**, the worst case would be **O(n²)** because that would be the size of the output.

Comment: I felt the same way. Best solution is O(n^2).

Comment: @Learner007: Your title says "Find **a** pair", not all pairs. So which is it?

Comment: GCD(prime number, non-prime number which is not a multiple of prime number considered) = 1, right? So, first find a prime number in the array, then, find a non-prime number which is not a multiple of prime number found. You have found a pair then. **Note: I haven't considered how much complex this algorithm will be.** A special case, if array contains 1, then pair of 1 with any number has GCD = 1.